# Update UIViewController when Core Data objects are updated

Tags: ios, swift, architecture

I want binding the dataSource and view controller

I use Core Data, and the dataSource is the an collection of `NSManagedObject`, when receive web socket notification, I update the data in Core Data, How can I let the view controller update UI automatically.

Comment: Lookup NSFetchedResultsController ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) if you are using a `UITableView`.
Else, you can use `NSNotificationCenter`. Demo use :

In your `ViewController`,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateUI:) name:@"updateUI" object:nil];
```

Post a notification to after updating the data

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateUI" object:nil];
```

Then in the method `updateUI`, you can do your UI updating stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use NSFetchResultsController, if your controller looks like a list of items.
The other option is to listen to the web socket notification, and just reload the UI whenever you get an answer.